# How can I get Complete error log from a device

Tags: android

How can I get the complete error log of an application crash (Force Close) When the application is installed on any user's device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download this app for get cat log [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks and I want to create this in my application when any error occurred it will automatically send the error log on the server with the user's permission .

Answer (score 2):

Is your app on Google Play? If so, just log into your developer account and Google collects stack traces for your app so you can diagnose and fix common crashes in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I once created an Applocker and does read from logcat.

```
    private static final String LogCatCommand = "logcat";

    Process process;
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(LogCatCommand);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Here's the full [source code](http://code.google.com/p/applocker/source/browse/trunk/AppLocker/src/com/gueei/applocker/DetectorService.java).

You need also `android.permission.READ_LOGS` permission.